# dynamically adjust height of ui tag, html

Tags: css, html-lists

I am trying to create a table view using ul tag in html. In the link I have used two li tags to create two column. I have used two images to show the spaces used by li tags, column dots and row dots. I have provided html, css and two images file.

images

[image: dots_column]
[image: dots_rows]
[image: screenshot of layout I got]

index.html -> http://pastebin.com/d8nq8pfr
style.css -> http://pastebin.com/V7iR3ZqE

Now if you see the layout created by provided files, you can see the second row of the table layout has irregular height. Both the height is from different ul tags.

So my question, is there any way I can make both of the height same (obviously the highest should be considered to make equal height ;) )?

Comment: I had uploaded two other images which are not visible here, but you need it if you want to try in your machine (the dots)

here are those files
http://i50.tinypic.com/63t4ig.gif (dots_column)
http://i45.tinypic.com/vzvsxu.gif (dots_row)

Comment: Out of curiosity, why won't you use tables if the content is suitable for such display? Would make it easier to vertically align your content and make more sence semantically.

Comment: Not convinced this is tabular data, hard to tell with the provided sample.  Also, no need for background images:  `border: 1px dotted`

Answer (score 0):

*If* this is tabular data, it should be in a table.  You can make other elements behave like tables with some limitations (no rowspans/colspans, etc):

```
#title1, #title2 {
    display: table-cell;
}
```

This does not work in IE7 or older.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously consider whether this is tabular data - and if so, use `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>`, etc. Tables aren't evil, they just shouldn't be used for things that aren't tables. And the word "table" has a pretty broad definition... even using them for structuring forms isn't *incorrect* (although probably a bit of a semantic grey area).

However, if you decide that semantically this really is an unordered list, you can use the [CSS table model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#table-display) to display elements "tabularly", by applying `display: table`, `display: table-row` and `display: table-cell` styles to the elements which could otherwise be `<table>`, `<tr>` and `<td>` elements respectively. See that link for the full set of values. These aren't supported in older browsers, mind (IE7 and earlier).

If you have to support IE7 (or even, god forbid, IE6), you'll have to resort to column layout patterns, which have thousands of articles dedicated to them around the internet.